# Show Chart from Previous Node if Data does not exist for the current node in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vis.js, react-vis-network

I am currently working on implementing a **chart** which has **different nodes** (**Network Chart**).

Initially when the page is rendered, an API call is made which show network chart with different nodes. User can **doublelick** on Node and it will render a **new chart** for the **selected Node**. User can continue to click on nodes (parent -> child1 -> child2 -> child3). This is working fine.

In some scenarios, when a user double click a **node**, we **do not** have data from the API. In this case, we need to show error pop-up and also need to **reload the chart** with the **previous node** (parent node).

Here is the example of network chart looks like https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/basicUsage.html

I am having difficulty in loading the **previous node** data when there is NO data from API call.

Here is pseudo code.

```
const NetworkGraph = (props: any) => {
  
  const container = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
  const [nodeId, setNodeId] = useState(props.nodeId)
  const { graphData, isLoading } = useGetNetowrkGraphData(nodeId); //Custom hook making API call
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoading === false) {
      if (graphData.nodes.length <= 0) {
        setMessage('No data found', 'error');
        //TODO: Here I need to set the previous NodeId and show previous graph
      }

      const nodes = new DataSet(graphData.nodes);
      const edges = new DataSet(graphData.edges as any[]);
      const networkData = { nodes: nodes, edges: edges };

      const network = container.current && new Network(container.current, networkData, options);

      network?.on('doubleClick', function (params) {
        var ids = params.nodes;
        var clickedNodes = nodes.get(ids);

        if (clickedNodes && clickedNodes.length > 0) {
          setNodeId(clickedNodes[0].id);
        }
      });
    }
  }, [
    container,
    nodeId,
    graphData.nodes,
    graphData.edges,
    isLoading,
    setNodeId,
    setMessage,
  ]);

  if (isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>;

  return (
    <>
      <Div>
          <div ref={container}/>
      </Div>
    </>
  );
};

export default NetworkGraph;
```